# Including files generated inside PostBuildEvent into ClickOnce deployment happens in race condition and sometimes doesn't work correctly

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

I have a WPF project. Its `.csproj` file contains a `<PostBuildEvent>` - there runs a script which produces some extra files. *The size of one of them is almost 20 MB, and the project itself is pretty large - it may be important to reproduce the issue.*

I would like to deploy these files along with the project via ClickOnce. So later in the `.csproj` I write:

```
<Content Include="$(PathToDirectoryWithProducedFiles)\**\*">
    <Link>$(PathRelativeToOutput)\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</Link>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
</Content>
```

This does **usually** work, but not always.
**Sometimes** the files just are not put into the `publish` folder, and **sometimes** ClickOnce installer produces an error `"File, [filewhichweights20MB], has a different computed hash than specified in manifest"`.

I have a clear feeling there is a race condition between ClickOnce deployment process and the script inside `<PostBuildEvent>`. Sometimes the script produces all files in time, and sometimes ClickOnce tries to copy the directory before they are completely generated.

I've tried to specify each file in different `<Content>` tags separately, but it doesn't work. Moreover, in theory there may be a situtation when the script produces different files, so this workaround will become useless.

The questions are:

- When (after what stage of build process) does ClickOnce exactly copy `<Content>` files and folders into the `publish` folder?
- Why there is a race condition there, as in theory `<PostBuildEvent>` is a part of build process?
- **[The main one]** How do I include files produced inside the `<PostBuildEvent>` script into the deploy correctly to get rid of infrequent but very annoying deployment errors? (And not to use `mage.exe` as using it would be more complicated)